# submit multiple value in same parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two input text that has same parameter, I want to submit it and expect to have affected 2 rows in my database

**views**

```
HTML

'<input name="campaign_name" value="campaign_name_1"  class="form-control" type="text">'
'<input name="campaign_name" value="campaign_name_2"  class="form-control" type="text">'
```

**controller**

```
    public function ajax_update()
    {
        $campaign_name=$this->input->post('campaign_name');
        {
        $data = [

                'campaign_name' => $campaign_name,

                ];
    }
            $insert = $this->cs->save($data);

        echo json_encode("status" => TRUE));
    }
```

**model**

```
    public function save($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }
```

**the ajax in html**

```
function edit_cs(id)
{
    save_method = 'update';
    $('#form')[0].reset(); 
    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); 
    $('.help-block').empty(); 


    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('cs/ajax_edit/')?>/" + id,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        {


// the data came from this "dataa"
dataa = [{ campaign_name: "eedfefs",status: 1},
{campaign_name:"aarar",status:2}];
console.log(dataa);

for (var i = 0; i < dataa.length; i++) {
            var campaign_name = dataa[i].campaign_name;
            var badges = document.createElement('div');
            badges.className = 'badges';
            badges.innerHTML =

                '<input name="campaign_name[]" value="'+campaign_name+'"  id="campaign_name"class="form-control" type="text">';

                    document.getElementById('case2').appendChild(badges);


 }


                        $('#modal_form').modal('show'); 
                        $('.modal-title').text('Call Action'); 
             }
        }

    });
}


function save()
{


    var url = "<?php echo site_url('cs/ajax_update')?>";
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {

            if(data.status) //if success close modal and reload ajax table
            {
                $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
                reload_table();
            }


    });
}
```

I think the problem is to outsmart the controller to be able  get the array from two  input text.notice that it already work if only I insert one input text

Comment: do you want each campaign name to be a new insert? what does your db schema look like? add you ajax code

Comment: yes sir,I jus added my ajax html in my code above

Comment: show *full* ajax code and post db schema

Comment: the db schema just like in my model that's it, code just updated again ,If I use **implode** it already work ,consider that controller get the array but it just merge it into one string and evetuanlly only affected one row.

Comment: your model tells me nothing about your db table except that it has a column called campaign name. you have yet to describe why you are using an array as an input. if you use implode then all the campaign names will be in the same db row under the column `campaign_name`, is that what you are trying to achieve? if so then you should just use one input and write all the campaign names out there. or do you want to have each campaign name a new row? so foreach campaign_name[] input the value begins a new row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate a row for each campaign at the same time and get the proper amount of `affected_rows()` back you need to use `insert_batch()`:

First, you need to follow pradeeps answer and properly define the inputs as an array:

```
'<input name="campaign_name[]" value="campaign_name_1"  class="form-control" type="text">'
'<input name="campaign_name[]" value="campaign_name_2"  class="form-control" type="text">'
```

Second, you need to properly format the input array for batch insert:

```
public function ajax_update() {
    $campaign_name = $this->input->post('campaign_name');
    if (!empty($campaign_name)) {
        $data = array();
        foreach ($campaign_name as $val) {
            $data[]['campaign_name'] = $val;
        }
        $rows = $this->cs->save($data); // will return proper num of affected rows;
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("status" => FALSE));
    }
}
```

and make a small modification to the `save()` method:

```
public function save($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert_batch($this->table, $data);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use inputs with the same name, it will overread.
You can put [] after the name what makes them will be as an array,
Example of that:

```
<input name="campaign_name[]" value="campaign_name_1"  class="form-control" type="text">
<input name="campaign_name[]" value="campaign_name_2"  class="form-control" type="text">
```

the first input with the 'campaign_name_1' value will be in the array as a first index (0) and the second input will be the next index and etc.

```
echo $_POST['campaign_name'][0];
echo $_POST['campaign_name'][1];
```

will echo

```
campaign_name_1
campaign_name_2
```

In the AJAX function, you should treat in the same way.

Comment: I tried that man but still not working,do you know where I can debug or echo the $_POST[campaign_name]? in the controller or model?

Comment: let's see you ajax code, add it to the question. and you echo in controller. you can view the response in dev tools network > 'page name' > response